# Comparing Strings To Ensure "RickAstley" is the only thing that can trigger song

Tags: javascript

I'm making a horror game
and I'm adding in an easter egg in which "Never Gonna Give You Up" plays if "RickAstley" is in the textbox. (shown in code) But when the text is anything else, Never Gonna Give You Up still plays. I have tried using `if else` and `else` , but they don't work. Is there a way to fix this using if statements?

```
    if(text.value== "RickAstley"){
       snd1.pause();
       snd2.play();
       snd2.volume=1;

    } 
    if(text.value!=="RickAstley"){
       snd1.play();
       snd2.pause();
    }
 }
```

Comment: so if never gonna give you up plays in either case, why do you need to check anything? always play it?

Comment: I am trying to make sure it ONLY plays when "RickAstley" is in the textbox

Comment: @luk2302 did my recent edits help?
what do I do now

Comment: So what you're saying is that you're rickrolling yourself while you debug this?

Comment: @LieutenantLark: so after you changed your code as you changed the question, it still doesn't work?

Comment: yes @JoachimSauer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it, everyone

```
if(text=="RickAstley"){
bobux();
entername();
}if(text!="RickAstley"){
//normal code here
}
```

Comment: turns out that "text.value" was supposed to be "text" since text=the value of the div element.